# Questions on series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

We know that if $\sum a_{n}$, $\sum b_{n}$ and $\sum c_{n}$ are convergent series (converging respectively to A,B and C), and if $c_{n}=a_{0}b_{n}+a_{1}b_{n-1}+...+a_{n}b_{0}$, then $C=AB$.

What happens if we do not know if $\sum c_{n}$ converges? I mean, do we have the following theorem also: If $\sum a_{n}$, $\sum b_{n}$  are convergent series (to A and B), and if $c_{n}=a_{0}b_{n}+a_{1}b_{n-1}+...+a_{n}b_{0}$ then $\sum c_{n}$ is a convergent serie and its sum is $AB$. If it is not true in general, then under which condition could it be true?

My second question is: if $\sum_{0}^{n}a_{n}\leq \sum_{0}^{n}b_{n}$, then do we have $A\leq B$ (where $A$ is $\sum a_{n}$ and $B$ is $\sum b_{n}$).

Thank you in advance for your answers

Comment: Make an attempt to answer the second question yourself.

Comment: Ask only one question per post, please.

Answer (score 2):

The first question, when $\sum a_n$(or $\sum b_n$) is absolutely convergent, the theorem is true. (In fact, it is the theorem 3.50 in baby rudin)

The second question, Assume that $\sum_0^n a_n=A_n$, $\sum_0^n b_n=B_n$, Then $$\lim_{n\to\infty}A_n=A, \lim_{n\to\infty}B_n=B$$
According to Theorem 3.3 in baby rudin
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(A_n-B_n)=A-B$$
We know $A_n\le B_n$, so $A\le B$.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

For you first question, it is not true in general, take for example $A=B=\sum_n \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}$. The absolute convergence of $A$ or $B$ and the convergence of the other (Mertens theorem) assure that $C$ is convergent.

For your second question, it is effectively true, by just taking limit in both side.

Comment: Thank you very much!